# Git cannot push code to bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-push

I just created a new repository on Bitbucket. I have existing code on my system.
I navigated to the root directory of my project and executed the code below:

```
git init
git add --all
git commit -m 'Initial commit'
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:<team>/<repo name>.git
git push origin master
```

Running the last command gives me the following error:

> fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

By the way, I'm using git via `https`. Earlier it used to ask me for my Bitbucket password, but it didn't even prompt for the password this time.

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change to https instead of ssh by
running this command

```
git remote set-url origin https://<repo_owner_name>@bitbucket.org/<teamname>/<reponame>.git
```